# What is the grooviest way to get the average of integers from a file?

Tags: groovy

I have a file with integers for which I want the average. Below is what I came up with and it works, but was wondering if there was a better (groovier) way..

```
 File myFile = new File("myListOfNumbers.txt")
 int total = 0
 int count = 0
 myFile.eachLine {line->
  total = Integer.parseInt(line) + total
  count++
 }
println "Avg is ${total /count}"
```

Comment: You should declare `total` as `long`, in case your file has many lines and/or big `int` values that cannot be added to an `int` without overflowing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for more declarative approach then you could do something like this:

```
def avg2 = myFile.readLines()
        .sum({ it.toInteger() }) / myFile.readLines().size()
```

The only problem is that this is not very efficient, because here we are calling `readLines()` method twice. Of course we could split declaration from this expression to make code more efficient and then we will end up with something like this:

```
def lines = myFile.readLines()
def avg2 = lines.sum({ it.toInteger() }) / lines.size()
```

#### Mixing with Java 8 Stream API

Of course you can always mix Groovy approach with Java 8 approach and use built-in `.average()` method from Java Stream API. In this case your code would look similar to this one:

```
def avg1 =  Files.lines(myFile.toPath())
        .mapToInt({ s -> s.toInteger() })
        .average()
        .getAsDouble()
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can skip the `collect` and convert to integer inside `sum`.

Comment: @doelleri Thanks for the input!

Comment: The stream-based answer is beautiful too, and has the advantage of working with huge files without loading everything into memory

Comment: @qlown The stream based answer will load everything into memory.  `readLines()` will load it all, and `average()` requires all elements loaded even if it didn't

Comment: @tim_yates Ah, yes, `Files.lines()` would have been better for that than `.readLines()`. But `average()` does not need all lines of file in memory, not even the integer values. It (`java.util.IntPipeline::average`) collects the values into a `long[2]` by summing them in `[1]` & increment a counter in `[0]`, and does the division at the end. So @Szymon here is a suggestion to use `Files.lines()` instead :)

Comment: @qlown Thanks for your very useful input!

Answer (score 6):

#### Groovier:

```
def mean = myFile.readLines().with { sum{it as Integer} / size() }
```

Uses groovyisms such as `with` and `as`.

Inside the closure passed to `with`, one can use `sum()` and `size()` directly, the target will be the object on which `.with` is invoked, in our case the list of lines.

#### Grooviest:

```
def mean = myFile.mean()
```

Of course I cheated, and did this beforehand:

```
File.metaClass.mean {
    delegate.readLines().with { sum{it as Integer} / size() }
}
```